# Get UNIX time FROM integers "year, month, day, and so on"

Tags: c++

I have

```
int year=2010;
int month=0; //starts from 0
int day=0;   //starts from 0
int hour=0;  //24 hours
int minute = 1 
int second= 20;
int millisec=90;
```

How can I convert them into `uint64_t` which contains milliseconds since Midnight Jan1 1970 (UTC time)?
Similar to UNIX time shown [here](https://currentmillis.com/)

So the 7 ints in the above example would become: `1573603280090`

```
uint64_t millisec = someFunction(); //<--which func to use?
```

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15957805/9007125) discusses how to retrieve the time from `chrono::time_point`, so it doesn't help me

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53677408/9007125) asks how to convert **string** into utc time, but I have integers and wish to use them directly.

Using C++17

Comment: May want to refer to the `tm` structure in `time.h` : https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.h.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a time into epoch time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979655/how-to-convert-a-time-into-epoch-time)

Comment: Assuming your input is UTC/Unix Time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158604/576911